# How to load text to paragraph dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

I want to have a paragraph that will dynamically change his content based on the link the mouse is hovering. My idea is to have multiple text files and then load the content as needed. I know how to get the elements but I struggle to load and set the text.

```js
  (function($) {
        var provider = $("p.content-provider");
        $("div.menu").find("li").on("mouseover", function (e) {
              var target = $(e.target).text().replace(" ","").toLowerCase() + ".txt";
               //get and set the text
          });
    })(jQuery);
```

I'm using Joomla so I'm constrained on HTML.

Also I would like to know if this approach will have a bad hit on performance?

Other and better suggestions in terms of performance and best practices are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. May have a delay during updating the text of the paragraph. because you will send an Ajax request to get file content.
2. Many requests will be sent to the server to get file content in each hover event.

You can preload all paragraphs content:

In this way, you can put each paragraph in a "p" tag and set the display of them to none. (display: none)

Also, you should set an attribute like "id" or "data-paraph" for access to them by referring to your "li".

Next, you can get the target paragraph content by hovering on each li.

```js
(function($) {
        var provider = $("p.content-provider");
        $("ul.menu").find("li").on("mouseover", function (e) {
              var paraphName = 'paraph-' + $(this).data('paraph');
              var text = $('p[data-paraph=' + paraphName + ']').text();
              
              provider.text(text);
              
          });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
.content-provider {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#preloaded-contents {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li data-paraph="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-paraph="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-paraph="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<p class="content-provider">
  Content Provider is here
</p>

<div id="preloaded-contents">
  <p class="preloaded-content" data-paraph="paraph-1">
    Paragraph content of item 1
  </p>
  <p class="preloaded-content" data-paraph="paraph-2">
    Paragraph content of item 2
  </p>
  <p class="preloaded-content" data-paraph="paraph-3">
    Paragraph content of item 3
  </p>
</div>
```